# Casting rvalue to lvalue in C programming language

Tags: c, casting, rvalue, lvalue

Hello I am a beginner learner in c , today I saw some tricky usage example code in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime)

`struct tm tm = *localtime(&(time_t){time(NULL)});`

**From my understanding** :  `time(NULL)` is a **rvalue** ( no name but movable ),
and if i change the code above to `(time_t)(time(NULL))`  , this will still be a **rvalue**( my compiler will give me an error says that you cannot get an address from this value ). And if i change the code to their usage `(time_t){time(NULL)}`  this time the compiler will not panic anything( now it's a **lvalue**).

Some people says the above code temporarily defined a structure in type `(time_t)` ( Are they correct  ?) .

and some other people did a test on their C++ compiler ( please explain ) :

says `(time_t){time(NULL)}` this will still be a **rvalue** which is opposite  to the C programming language .

**Questions:**

Is that indicates  `(cast_type){rvalue}` this will eventually be a **lvalue** in C ?

Is this a common usage in C?

Is it a sematic difference between C and C++ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `(time_t){ time(NULL) }` is a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)<sup>C99</sup>, initialized by the return value of [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time). From the linked documentation

> The value category of a compound literal is lvalue (its address can be taken).

> Although the syntax of a compound literal is similar to a cast, the important distinction is that a cast is a non-lvalue expression while a compound literal is an lvalue.

Some C++ compilers support compound literals as an extension. For example, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) details an extension in [§6.28 Compound Literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), but note this difference:

> In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration. In C++, a compound literal designates a temporary object that only lives until the end of its full-expression.

---

`(time_t)(time(NULL))` is a redundant, [explicit cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) of the return value of [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) to the type [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t). It is a *non-lvalue*.

Comment: "The value category of a compound literal is lvalue (its address can be taken). " This helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: @MosesChan, actually it can be even assigned. `(int){0} = 42;` is perfectly valid though useless C code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer provided by **Oka**.

My question now is cleared.

This kind of usage is called **compound literals** and it appears in `C99` and later standards.

The purpose of this usage is probably when someone wants to pass **an address** (where it could only be obtained by a lvalue , this is required by the compiler) of a function returned object ( which is a rvalue ) into another function by a pointer.

For exmaple (in our case) :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{
  // struct tm* localtime ( const time_t *timer);
  // time_t time ( time_t *arg);
  // char* asctime(const struct tm* time_ptr);

  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm* ptm = localtime(&t);

  printf("%s", asctime(ptm));

}
```

If we use the **compound litreal** instead , the example code (which is [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime)  provided would be:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    struct tm* ptm = localtime(&(time_t){time(NULL)});
    printf("%s", asctime(ptm));
}
```

Both results would be likely the following :

```
./main.out
Sat May 28 19:52:34 2022
```

And this probably would help to improve the code density and reduce the size of your program.

Comment: I think of compound literals as being an extension of C's string literals.  When you say `char *p = "Hello";`, you get an unnamed array for `p` to point to.  But that works only for arrays of `char`.  With compound literals, we can do the same for arrays of any type, and for structure types.